# how to save output from the shell by using python flask

Tags: python, bash, shell, flask

First of all, I am very new at programming.
I am trying to save a variable from bash shell

```
  >curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/
```

this line would return data such as local-ipv4. And I am trying to use phython and flask to save those variables. I wrote

```
from flask import Flask, request
app  = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/')
def testRequest():
  url1 = "http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/"
  name1 = request.get(url1)
  nameText = name1.text
  return nameText

testOutput = testRequest()
print testOutput
```

But this gives me runtime error : working outside of the request context.
can someone guide me to where to look for possible solution?

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4760215/4110233

Comment: I'm a little confused; are you trying to save data from *incoming* requests? Or are you trying to query url1 and return data from that? My understanding is that Flask's `request` is for the former, whereas you'd probably want to use the `requests` module for the latter. Looking at your code, it seems like `requests` is what you want, rather than Flask's `request`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To things to comment here:

1. First, it seems that you'll be just fine by using `requests`, a highly recommended library for HTTP requests. With it you could do:

   ```
   import requests
   url = "http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/"
   resp = requests.get(url)
   print resp.text
   ```
2. Regards to the error you're getting `runtime error : working outside of the request context`, is because by `testOutput = testRequest()` you're calling a method that's part of the `Flask` app `app`. Another thing related to the error is that you never ran the `Flask` app. To do this, include this at the end of your code.

   ```
    if __name__ == '__main__':
       app.run()
   ```

   But again, `Flask` is rather a web framework that it's useful to create web sites, APIs, web apps, etc. It's very useful, but I don't think you may need it for what you're trying to achieve.

Further info about `requests` and `Flask`:

- http://docs.python-requests.org/
- http://flask.pocoo.org/

Comment: Thank you so much! first method worked. The reason why I wanted to implement flask is that because I want to make the web apps by using those data. I guess I will implement flask later on. I am not very familiar with either flask or python...

Answer (score 1):

Since you only need to make an HTTP GET request and print the response, you don't need Flask. You can use the `urllib` standard library to send the GET request (https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html):

```
import urllib.request

def testRequest():
  url1 = "http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/"
  response = urllib.request.urlopen(url1)
  nameText = response.read().decode('utf-8')
  return nameText

testOutput = testRequest()
print testOutput
```